# Why is not posible to declare border properties in CSS like with margin or padding border:1px 2px 3px 0px solid #333;

Tags: css

Why is not possible to declare border properties like margin or padding.???

`p{padding:100px auto 100px auto}` or `p{margin:0 auto 0 auto}`

Do I always have to do:

```
border-top:0px;
border-right:1px solid #333;
border-bottom:1px solid #333;
border-left:3px solid #333;
```

would be awesome to able to do.. border:0 1px 1px 3px solid #333; is an alternate way to do this?

Comment: You can, it's just that borders have many more attributes than a simple size value that margins/padding have. So you can't use the shorthand for one single value on a `border: ...` declaration. You can use the shorthand for individual components, like border-width.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorthand `border-width` property for width. You define the color and style using `border` (or even `border-style` and `border-color`):

```
border: solid #333;
border-width: 0px 1px 1px 3px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can. You should use `border-width`